# SpringBoot docker connect to mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, containers

I pulled mysql docker image and run container with command:

```
docker run --name myapp-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest
```

At this point springBoot locally is working. It is connected with mysql:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Now I want springBoot app also to be on separate docker container, on the same server. For that I'm using Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/myapp.jar myapp.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

I'm starting this image with:

```
docker run --name myapp -p 8080:8080 -it myapp:latest
```

Now springBoot container cannot find myslq container.
I try:

```
docker run --name myapp -p 8080:8080 --link=myapp-mysql:mysql -it myapp:latest
```

But again it cannot connect to mysql container. How can I connect springBoot container to mysql container?

I also tried to change application.properties to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://myapp-mysql:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

and start springBoot with:

```
docker run --name myapp -p 8080:8080 --link=myapp-mysql:mysql -it myapp:latest
```

Again it cannot connect to db:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot cannot connect to MySQLand exits in Docker/Docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678113/spring-boot-cannot-connect-to-mysqland-exits-in-docker-docker-compose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to link the containers, I will suggest look into docker-compose.

If you don't want to use docker-compose then,

First of all, In your springboot properties file, change the url to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://[container-name]:3306/mydb
```

In your case,

```
docker run --name myapp-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest
```

container-name: myapp-mysql

then try to run both containers.

if it doesn't work then look into docker networks & put the containers in same network.

[Docker Network Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWEYp.png)